# How to remove space from the top in react-drawer

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-drawer

I am using it and i am getting white space at the top. Can any provide me detail to remove this white space from top.
@react-navigation/drawer[image]

Answer (score 11):

You can use this if the status bar is hidden:

```
<DrawerContentScrollView 
    contentContainerStyle={{ paddingTop: 0 }}>
</DrawerContentScrollView>
```

Answer (score 8):

In DrawerContentScrollView there is a default padding of 4 was added in @react-navigation/drawer code so to remove this just pass paddingTop prop in contentContainerStyle.

```
const insets = useSafeArea();

<DrawerContentScrollView
    contentContainerStyle={{
       paddingTop: insets.top,
    }}
   {...props}>
</DrawerContentScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd guessed there was some padding but didn't know there was a `contentContainerStyle` property

Answer (score 4):

Just to add, I had the same problem and useSafeArea is deprecated.
I managed using useSafeAreaInsets.

```
import { useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

...<DrawerContentScrollView 
  style={styles.container} 
  contentContainerStyle={{
    paddingTop: insets.top,
 }}
>...
```